# Where clause alternative in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I've got my brain squeezed out trying to olve following issue. Hope you may help.

My datasource:

```
JrNo  JrLineNo  Employee  LineDescription
-----------------------------------------------
1     1         BBB       Target Description 01
1     2         AAA       Target Description 02
2     1         BBB       Target Description 03
2     2         DDD       Target Description 04
2     3         AAA       Target Description 05
2     4         CCC       Target Description 06
2     5         DDD       Target Description 07
3     1         AAA       Target Description 08
3     2         AAA       Target Description 09
3     3         BBB       Target Description 10
4     1         AAA       Target Description 11
4     2         DDD       Target Description 12
4     3         AAA       Target Description 13
4     4         CCC       Target Description 14
```

I have created report which is grouped by Employees (AAA, BBB, CCC, DDD)
On each group footer I want to see Description field of "LineDescription" column, filtered by the highest journal number and highest journal line number (within that journal) for every Employee.

For example: The highest journal number in above table is 4, but the highest journal line number is 5 (in jounal 2). If I roughly take Max of JrNo and Max of JrLineNo, it simply will not give expected result.

Expected result:

```
AAA  Target Description 13
BBB  Target Description 10
CCC  Target Description 14
DDD  Target Description 12
```

If I'd use SQL my query would look like:

```
SELECT LineDescription
FROM table
WHERE JrNo = (SELECT Max(JrNo) from table WHERE Employee = 'AAA')
AND JrLineNo = (SELECT Max(JrLineNo) FROM table 
               WHERE JrNo = (SELECT Max(JrNo) from table WHERE Employee = 'AAA'))
```

But I need to develop this in ssrs Expression way. And Iif function does not help much.

Any ideas - how to build expression which selects only one record based on multiple value filters and subqueries? What is alternative of WHERE clause?

Comment: I don't think what you're asking for is possible. Why not just do it within the SSRS dataset?

Comment: I have to agreed with cookie monster. It will be so much easier to do in your dataset. I know some people get data from Stored Procs and cannot mofidy them but you can get around that by dumping the stored proc results into a temp table and processing that as you wish for your report. So...  CREATE TABLE #t(JrNo INT, JrLineNo etc...) then INSERT INTO #t EXEC MyProc then you can have a party with #t and do what you want !

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I am not using pure SSRS. I am using 3rd party report designer, where I am not able to create datasets or custom SQL queries. The only tool that I can use, is ssrs expression syntax. But it has limited and poor language commands. For instance - using IIF I am not able to combine filter parameters. Actually I know what I need. I need an ability of building on-the-fly dataset (first query), and extract data form that dataset (subquery). But ssrs expression syntax does not allow such trick. Or, possibly I am not much master of SSRS. Anyway, I'd like to hear opinions